# Nodejs getting stuck after every command

Tags: node.js, centos7

I've managed to install nodejs package and it's not working as you can see in the images. I've tried every version from v10 to v15 and still the same thing.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GUHO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Find the npmrc file, delete it and delete all configurations for node, delete node as well and install it. When deleting node some of the configurations are not deleted so you'll have to delete it manually.

Comment: i don't think i have a npmrc file beacause i didn't have any project inside the vps, if this is a global file than how i can find it?
Also i tried to install nodejs on ubuntu and debian and i also have the same problem, could that be a problem from the server itself?